# unable to see changes in database

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm using Broadleaf Commerce 2.2 and unable to update my database with new product entry which i did from admin console. I would like to know that why my changes which i made in admin is not reflecting in database?

I added couple of new product through admin console in Broadleaf database but when i check this under database table i won't find any product there. Is there any way which i need to consider or setup??? how can i add more product from admin and see those under database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First migrate your database from hibernateSQl to Mysql.
then you have to made one change in development.resources after starting the jetty from
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop

to 
blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

if it doesnt works then you have to setup your whole demosite in tomcat server by just delpoying the .war file of your project in tomcat webapp folder.

and do the same changes in development.properties after starting the tomcat ..

It will surely work for you.